# evil visual mode selection

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

[image]

The behavior of evil visual mode is a little unexpected. First, I set the mark at the top '(defhydra', then use C-n to move the point down, everything goes all right until I hit the last line ("q" nil), the cursor move down two lines all of a sudden and get the blank line selected. I personally do not like this behavior, so is there any way to modify this. I dig into the evil source code, but still struggling. Any suggestion is welcome.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you post the cursor and selection before and after pressing `C-n` the final time? Does you get the same issue when using `j` instead of `C-n`?

Comment: Thanks, j and C-n are bound to the same function. The testing results have been updated. The blank line affects the behavior, apparently.